# Вывести на экран аббревиатуру месяца

Tags: python, строки

```
months = "JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec"
n = int(input("Enter a month number"))
```

Выше - это исходные данные. Нужно вывести на экран аббревиатуру месяца, основываясь на числе, которое вводит пользователь. Остановился на типа таком, есть еще много подобных вариантов...

```
for i in range(len(months)):
    print(months[n])
```

Но это не то.

Укажите направление, куда думать, кроме направлений из 3-х букв и т.д. ))

Comment: Спасибо! за ответ

Comment: @Oposum, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант, можно преобразовать исходную строку в список строк:

```
months_list = [months[i*3:(i+1)*3] for i in range(12)]
```

и дальше делать

```
print(months_list[n-1])
```

Обращаться с этим списком будет удобнее и несколько эффективнее, чем каждый раз делать срез, чтобы получить название месяца.

Comment: ох ох спасибо, когда я уже научюсь таким трюкам))

Comment: @Oposum: можно ещё так: `month_abbr = ['']+[months[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(months), 3)]` это [общий способ обхода списка по `n` элементов за раз](http://stackoverflow.com/a/434328).

Comment: @jfs, сишник внутри меня говорит, что добавление дополнительного пустого элемента в начало списка вместо вычитания 1 из номера месяца неоптимально (лишние действия, дополнительная память и т.д.). Питонист говорит, что в данном случае это не критично.

В остальном ваш вариант интересен, как всегда.

Answer (score 2):

Входной формат не очень удачный, вместо этого [можно использовать `calendar.month_abbr`](http://ideone.com/Y8q1yu), который может зависеть от текущей локали:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from calendar import month_abbr

month_number = int(input("Enter a month number (Jan -> 1): "))
print(month_abbr[month_number])
```

Comment: Спасибо, это интересно.

Answer (score 1):

```
months[(n-1)*3:n*3]
```